# Is there a way to use gazebo with kinetic yet?

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey I have ubuntu 16.04 with kinetic installed but I want to use gazebo, how can I do it ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286717/is-there-a-way-to-use-gazebo-with-kinetic-yet-?/) by [Prof. xavier](https://answers.ros.org/users/33886/prof.-xavier/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-03-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To install Gazebo stand-alone:

```
sudo apt-get install gazebo7
```

But to use it with ROS:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs
```

See also [gazebosim.org/Installing gazebo_ros_pkgs](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_installing).

Is something not working for you?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0